# Generalization: $x=\text{sup}\{q\in \mathbb{Q}:q<x\}$

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

How do I prove that $x=\text{sup}\{q\in \mathbb{Q}:q<x\}$? Provided that $x\in\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathbb R$? For $q\in\mathbb Q$, what is the element corresponding to $q$ in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Have you noticed how I removed the elementary set theory tag from all your questions about sets of rational numbers? Can you guess why?

Comment: Removing the tag makes it so that a curious soul *naively* mining math.stackexchange.com doesn't get good results when searching strings like "rational set supremum" or "set-theoretic supremum rational."

Comment: Loie, this question **isn’t** about elementary set theory. It also isn’t really about calculus; it fits the real analysis tag somewhat better.

Comment: "rob people of knowledge"... Sure, and @Asaf eats children, too.

Comment: Loie, tags are supposed to be used according to what the terms *actually mean*, not what people might think they mean. I have edited your comment to make it less rude; please try to be more civil in the future.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $\alpha=\sup\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<x\}$; you want to show that $\alpha=x$. One way to do this is to rule out the possibility that $\alpha<x$ and the possibility that $\alpha>x$.

- Suppose that $\alpha<x$; then there a rational number in the interval $(\alpha,x)$. Why is that impossible?
- Suppose that $\alpha>x$; can it then actually be true that $\alpha$ is the **least** upper bound of $\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<x\}$?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show that

1. $\text{sup}\{q\in \mathbb{Q}:q<x\} \le x$

and

1. For any $y < x$ there is a
   $r \in \{q\in \mathbb{Q}:q<x\}$
   such that $r > y$.

Comment: What? To show $a\leq b$ means showing $(a<b)\lor(a=b)$...

Comment: Do you understand what it means for x to be a least upper bound? It means that x is an upper bound (so criterion 2) and that it is the least upper bound (criterion 1)